# checking list against filtered list in python

Tags: python, linux, loops

the initial scope of this project was to  grab a list of nics from a linux server and check for up status, this part works as expected.
Now I am adding network statistics for it and am able to get it working for a single interface now when I try to combine them I have some issues which I am trying to get sorted.

When I run the following code I get this error:
File "test.py", line 58, in 
RX = float(STATS[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

```
SIOCGIFFLAGS = 0x8913
null256 = '\0'*256
filtered_interfaces = list(filter(lambda i: re.findall(r'enp[0-3]n',i), interfaces()))
STATS = []

# Create a socket so we have a handle to query
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
def getNicStatus():
# Call ioctl(  ) to get the flags for the given interface
    for interface in filtered_interfaces:
        result = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(  ), SIOCGIFFLAGS, interface + null256)

# Extract the interface's flags from the return value
        flags, = struct.unpack('H', result[16:18])

# Check "UP" bit and print a message
        up = flags & 1
        print(('DOWN', 'UP')[up], interface)
# Return a value suitable for shell's "if"
    sys.exit(not up)


#getNicStatus()
def rx():
 ifstat = open('/proc/net/dev').readlines()
 for interface in ifstat:
      if interface in filtered_interfaces:
       stat = float(interface.split()[1])
       STATS[0:] = [stat]

def tx():
 ifstat = open('/proc/net/dev').readlines()
 for interface in  ifstat:
      if filtered_interfaces == interface:
       stat = float(interface.split()[9])
       STATS[1:] = [stat]
print 'In   Out'
rx()
tx()
while True:
 time.sleep(1)
 rxstat_o = list(STATS)
 rx()
 tx()
 RX = float(STATS[0])
 RX_O = rxstat_o[0]
 TX = float(STATS[1])
 TX_O = rxstat_o[1]
 RX_RATE = round((RX - RX_O)/1024/1024,3)
 TX_RATE = round((TX - TX_O)/1024/1024,3)
 print RX_RATE ,'MB  ',TX_RATE ,'MB'
```

If I hardcode an interface value it works as expected, code for that here:

```
 INTERFACE = 'enp3n9'
STATS = []
print 'Interface:',INTERFACE
def rx():
 ifstat = open('/proc/net/dev').readlines()
 for interface in  ifstat:
  if INTERFACE in interface:
   stat = float(interface.split()[1])
   STATS[0:] = [stat]
def tx():
 ifstat = open('/proc/net/dev').readlines()
 for interface in  ifstat:
  if INTERFACE in interface:
   stat = float(interface.split()[9])
   STATS[1:] = [stat]
print 'In   Out'
rx()
tx()
while True:
 time.sleep(1)
 rxstat_o = list(STATS)
 rx()
 tx()
 RX = float(STATS[0])
 RX_O = rxstat_o[0]
 TX = float(STATS[1])
 TX_O = rxstat_o[1]
 RX_RATE = round((RX - RX_O)/1024/1024,3)
 TX_RATE = round((TX - TX_O)/1024/1024,3)
 print RX_RATE ,'MB  ',TX_RATE ,'MB'
```

can someone point me in the right direction for getting this to iterate through all of the nics?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. I fyou get `IndexError` for `STATS[0]` then this list is empty. Using `print()` you can check when if it adds elements to `STATS` or not. It is called `"print debuging"` OR learn how to use real debuger

Comment: @furas Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    print(STATS[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

and yes the list is empty, this pulls the list from dev as expected:
 for interface in  ifstat:

however when it compares to those in filtered_list it is not matching. (filtered list is valid as well)